# Laravel auth: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I was trying to implement basic user registration & login using 'auth'. I am able to create the migrations and the tables are already created in the database as well.
[image]

When I fill up the registration details such as Name, Email, Password & Confirm Password and hit register, I'm landing up in this error:

[image]

This is the code in my .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=townbakery
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=12345678!
```

I've added any other code or have made any other changes except changing the Route web.php as

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('auth.login');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Please help me where I've gone wrong. This is the first application I'm working on after learning laravel basics.

Database.php looks like:

```
mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

Here is my User.php model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to clear config cache with `php artisan config:cache`, `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear`?

Comment: How does your config/database.php look like?

Comment: @LucasArbex I've cleared config cache but still getting the same error

Comment: have you restarted your server? if not restart it

Comment: @dns_nx I've edited the question with Database.php

Comment: make sure your `DB_PASSWORD=12345678!` is correct.

Comment: @Laravel password is correct. I've cross-checked multiple times. Other Projects are running too using the same credentials.

Comment: Is the protected variable `$connection` set in your `User` model ?

Comment: set new password.

Comment: Show your user model code.

Comment: @N69S No, how should I set this variable?

Comment: @Laravel Question is edited with User.php model

Comment: All is perfect I can't see anything wrong here. Even without connection, you couldn't migrate. What is your Laravel version?

Comment: @Laravel All my previous sample projects it is working fine. But now when I make new projects this is happening. Tables are also created.

Comment: If your migration is working, it means your `.env` credentials are correct, but somewhere, something isn't using them. If you have other array values in `connections` in `config/database.php`, delete them, and see if you get a different error, or explicitly add `protected $connection = "mysql";` to all models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One last possibility would be that your server is forcing the value of the env variable `DB_PASSWORD` ether through Vhost or .htaccess

To verify this, try changing your `.env` variable to `DB_T_PASSWORD=12345678!` and dont forget to change it in `database.php` config file `'password' => env('DB_T_PASSWORD', ''),`

Comment: Changing as per recommendation worked for me. Is there something I could do to fix this?

Comment: if you have access to the vhost configuration, you can start there.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error and solved. First try:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

than, restart your server:

```
php artisan serve
```

Before the solution, I tried to write username, password and database name as hard coded in database.php. After I changed username and password, it was trying to find a database called laravel. It's clear that **this is related with the first config file .env.example** more clearly, it's related with config cache. So delete all possible cache combinations possible.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue of SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO). I resolved the problem by just creating a new user with password into mysql db and updated the .env file accordingly. I came out that the problem was resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
DB_DATABASE=townbakery

DB_USERNAME=root

DB_PASSWORD=
```